# Unable to boot Ubuntu on a laptop with two hard drives

Tags: dual-boot

I have an HP-Omen with 128 GB SSD and 1 TB HDD with Windows 10 installed on the SSD. I partitioned the HDD and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it.   However, I am not able to boot Ubuntu. Every time I reboot, the laptop boots directly into Windows 10.

Any suggestions on how to boot into Ubuntu, or on how to customize the Ubuntu installation to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should enter BIOS/UEFI Setup and choose 1 TB HDD as first booting device in boot priority menu. Then in Ubuntu just run `sudo update-grub` to be able to boot to windows from grub2.